# Получить ближайшие по индексу значения датафрейма

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Имеется dataframe df

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```py
print(type(df.index[0]))
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
```

Из столбцов max_high и max_rsi_14 нужно получить две **равные по длине** серии данных. В первой серии должны быть все не пустые значения из max_high, а во второй значения max_rsi_14 ***только ближайшие* по индексу к не пустому значению max_high**.

*Пример желаемого итога:*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Пробовал решать с помощью

```py
df.index.get_loc(dt, method='nearest')
```

Но не смог разобраться. Пожалуйста помогите и спасибо за помощь!

---

**Пример датасета**

```py
                       high     low     volume    open     ...      min_high  max_high  min_rsi_14  max_rsi_14
timestamp                                                  ...
2018-10-02 11:00:00  6553.0  6542.5   25845962  6552.0     ...           NaN       NaN         NaN         NaN
2018-10-02 12:00:00  6574.0  6534.0   99602546  6542.5     ...           NaN    6574.0         NaN   44.320898
2018-10-02 13:00:00  6557.0  6542.0   42124982  6552.0     ...           NaN       NaN         NaN         NaN
2018-10-02 14:00:00  6552.5  6497.0  136742416  6549.5     ...           NaN       NaN   34.712926         NaN
2018-10-02 15:00:00  6529.5  6505.5   55167626  6519.0     ...           NaN       NaN         NaN   39.25009
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [pd.merge_asof()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
res = pd.merge_asof(df.loc[df['max_high'].notna(), 'max_high'], 
                    df.loc[df['max_rsi_14'].notna(), 'max_rsi_14'],
                    left_index=True, 
                    right_index=True,
                    direction='nearest')
```

Пример:

```
In [36]: df
Out[36]:
                     max_high  max_rsi_14
timestamp
2018-10-02 11:00:00       NaN         NaN
2018-10-02 12:00:00    6574.0   44.320898
2018-10-02 13:00:00       NaN         NaN
2018-10-02 14:00:00    6666.0         NaN
2018-10-02 15:00:00       NaN   39.250090

In [37]: %paste
res = pd.merge_asof(df.loc[df['max_high'].notna(), 'max_high'],
                                        df.loc[df['max_rsi_14'].notna(), 'max_rsi_14'],
                                        left_index=True,
                                        right_index=True,
                                        direction='nearest')

## -- End pasted text --

In [38]: res
Out[38]:
                     max_high  max_rsi_14
timestamp
2018-10-02 12:00:00    6574.0   44.320898
2018-10-02 14:00:00    6666.0   39.250090
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Как всегда очень помогли. Уже читаю про функцию =)