# Выборка наименьших ближайших дат в DF2 из значений в DF1

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Необходимо выбрать ближайшую дату в DF1, к каждой из дат DF2. Добавив соответствующий столбец с дельтой.
df1

```
0    2021-11-16 19:07:00.332
2    2021-08-11 14:11:02.025
4    2021-04-09 18:23:33.182
6    2021-04-02 15:56:30.064
7    2021-04-02 15:56:15.816
8    2021-03-15 13:04:55.310
9    2021-03-15 13:02:41.176
10   2021-03-15 13:02:31.547
11   2021-03-10 13:19:46.228
12   2021-03-07 16:49:54.026
13   2021-02-24 15:25:36.165
14   2021-02-24 15:19:26.442
15   2021-01-31 09:31:52.686
16   2021-01-31 09:25:50.750
17   2020-11-20 17:54:36.323
18   2020-11-19 17:44:27.850
Name: Дата, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

df2

```
1   2021-10-16 11:58:12.969
3   2021-05-21 17:15:33.134
5   2021-04-02 15:56:38.822
Name: Дата, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Решение которое вижу я это вычесть все значения в df1 из каждой строки df2 и дальше используя .idxmin найти значения.

Решение не работает.

```
df2.sub(df1).idxmax()
```

В итоге должно получится

```
    1   2021-10-16 11:58:12.969   66
    3   2021-05-21 17:15:33.134   42
    5   2021-04-02 15:56:38.822   0
```

Comment: pandas.merge_asof

Comment: [похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/975007/211923)

Comment: Решение подойдёт только для сортированных списков. Нужно более универсальное решение

Answer (score 1):

возможно подойдет что-то такое (решение те тестировалось):

```
df2['delta'] = df2.apply(lambda x: (df1 - x).abs().min(), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Рабочий вариант

```
df3 = df2.apply(lambda x: (df1 - x))
df3['Дата'] = df3[df3 < '0'].abs().min(axis = 1)
```

В итоге добавилась необходимость сортировать ещё и по номерам, пока не реализовано.

```
df1

  Номер    Дата
0   1     2021-11-16 19:07:00.332
2   1     2021-08-11 14:11:02.025
4   1     2021-04-09 18:23:33.182
6   17    2021-04-02 15:56:30.064
7   17    2021-04-02 15:56:15.816
    ...

df2

      Номер    Дата
1       1      2021-10-16 11:58:12.969
3       1      2021-05-21 17:15:33.134
5       17     2021-04-02 15:56:38.822
```

Временное решение пока такое, без сортировки, возвращает только для одного номера

```
df3 = df2['Дата'].apply(lambda x: (df1['Дата'] - x))
df3['Дата'] = df3[df3 < '0'].abs().min(axis = 1)
itog = pd.merge(df2['Номер'], df3['Дата'], how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```